# How to access and read Postgres views in R

Tags: r, postgresql, view, sqldf, r-dbi

I am trying to access and read tables and views of Postgres database in R. I am able to get the tables using `dbListTables` function using `RPostgres` package but facing issues with `views`.

As having naive knowledge of postgres, looking for ways to access and read views as well in R.

```r
library(RPostgres)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

pw<- {
"password"
}

conn <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres()
             , host="host-name"
             , port='5432'
             , dbname="database-name"
             , user="username"
             , password=pw)

dbExistsTable(conn, "Test_Table")
#TRUE
dbListTables(conn)

mydf <- dbReadTable(conn, "Test_Table") # To Read the table in R
```

I have also tried the below command as per this link: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1007 but no success.

```sql
SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
WHERE table_schema = ANY (current_schemas(false));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `dbExistsTable` and `dbListTables` cannot see Postgres views.

But you should be able to find them with a query like this one:

```sql
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') and table_type = 'VIEW'
```

Once you know the name of the view you're looking for, `dbReadTable(conn, "myview")` works.

Note: if it still doesn't work, make sure to set the right schema using

```sql
SET search_path to myschema
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the sql query which you suggested. Surprisingly, it didn't. Just the silly question, the query which u have suggested is from R Side ? Also, dbReadTable(conn, "vw_activeIngredient") for View also gives error: Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  ERROR:  relation "vw_activeIngredientBeta" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM  "vw_activeIngredient"

Comment: You can either use the above query in a tool like pgAdmin, or from R using `dbGetQuery(conn, "text of the query")`. If it still doesn't work, what is the error message you get?

Comment: dbGetQuery part worked perfectly but reading of view still gives error dbReadTable(conn, "vw_country") Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  ERROR:  relation "vw_country" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM  "vw_country"

Comment: Can you see `vw_country` in the resultset of `dBGetQuery`?

Comment: Yes it is coming with dBGetQuery. I am able to see all the views of the database.

Comment: OK, then say `myschema` is the name of the corresponding schema (which you can read on the same row as `vw_country`). Try `dbGetQuery(conn, "SET search_path to myschema")` followed by `dbReadTable(conn, "vw_country")`.

Comment: dbGetQuery(conn, "SET search_path to myschema") followed by dbReadTable(conn, "vw_country") worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the view name is in quotes.

```sql
viewDataFrame <- dbGetQuery(con,'SELECT * FROM dh2."viewName"')
```

Note: The view name "viewName" is in quotes. It wont work otherwise.

Comment: I've got views under odd schema names, and this solution by Ramana works, without the quotes around "viewName".  The entire query should be in quotes ie. ...(con,"SELECT * FROM dh2.viewName")